# winforms control real client area

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I know the real client area of a control?

I have an app with a treeview. I do some low level manipulation to this treeview and I need to know the real client area of the control. So far I have used TreeView.Height/Width, but when the tree grows and a horizontal or vertical scroll bar appears, some of this space is used by the scrollbars.

I need a way to know the usable screen space on the treeview (the client area sans the space taken by the scrollbars, if they are shown). How can I get those values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [ClientRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle.aspx) property might work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Use ClientRectangle property.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with ClientRectangle is that it includes the space for the menuStrip and the Status strip.